# Linux Terminal Nmap several IP's at once

Tags: linux

I have a command that shows several IP's on a network at once, lets call it 'list'.  When I use this command, it shows the following, for example:

```
10.0.0.10        Server10                            
10.0.0.11        Server11                         
10.0.0.12        Server12                            
10.0.0.13        Server13
```

I would like to Nmap all of these at once, but just using a specific port, so basically "nmap 10.0.0.10 -p22" but I would like to prompt the user for which port to Nmap, and for Linux to do this with every server mentioned that is shown when 'list' is given.

Is this possible? Would this require an AWK script or similar?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Nmap does have a nice option which can be used to pass a list of host contained in a file. They should be a single host per line. Your output looks a lot like the actual input of nmap. You need to remove the second part. You could do this in multiple way, for example with a simple cut.

```
 list | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

Then you would need to have the user input a port. For this, you can simply use the read function

```
 read -e
```

For a whole line.

As I really like one liner, here is everything in a single line :

```
 port=$(read -e);nmap -iL <(list | cut -d ' ' -f1) -p $port;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could either do something like `nmap 10.0.0.10-13 -p22` (or whatever range you extract from the given list), or if you're wanting finer grained control over how the scan is performed, you'd need to use nmap's [scripting interface](http://nmap.org/book/nse.html), which makes use of [Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/#1ed).

For the latter, there are a **plethora** of examples available in most nmap distributions. e.g., on Ubuntu, check in `/usr/share/nmap/scripts`. Just grep for 'thread' in that directory (or where ever your system installs it) and you'll see what I mean. (: